# Is there a method to bind Tabulator to a dynamically created <div> element?

Tags: tabulator, dynamic-binding

I am attempting to bind an instance of the Tabulator plug-in to a dynamically created `<div>` element but to no avail.  I have no issue binding Tabulator to static elements created with the page load event; however, I need to be able to dynamically spawn new `<div>` elements containing Tabulator tables.

The HTML for the `<div>` placeholder and the code for the dynamically-created `<div>` are as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="CrewLeaderDiv" name="CrewLeader"></div>
```

JavaScript to create the new collection of nested `<div>` elements:

```
        $("#CrewLeader").change(function (element) {
            var selOption = $("#CrewLeader > option:selected");
            window.leaderID = selOption.val();
            var crewLeaderName = selOption.text()

            // Create the Crew Leader Time Card.
            var sHtml = "<div class='card' style='margin: 10px;'>";
            sHtml += "<div class='card-header col-sm-12 roundBorder' style='padding:2px;'>";
            sHtml += "<span class='col-sm-3 ' style='float:left; font-size:16px; text-align:right;'>Crew Leader:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
            sHtml += "<input id='CrewLeaderName' disabled class='col-sm-6 roundBorder' style='float:left; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:darkred; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center;' value='" + crewLeaderName + "' />";
            sHtml += "</div>";
            sHtml += "<div class='card-body col-sm-12 roundBorder' style='padding:4px; font-size:16px;'>Time Card Entries</div>";
            sHtml += "<div class='col-sm-12 roundBorder' id='CrewLeaderTable' style='font-size:12px;'></div>";
            sHtml += "<div class='btnCrewLeader'><button id='btnCrewLeader' class='btn btn-secondary' type='button'>Click to Enter Time</button></div>";
            sHtml += "</div>";
            $("#CrewLeaderDiv").html(sHtml);
        });
```

The sHtml string is passed to the #CrewLeaderDiv placeholder to create the Bootstrap card and a  placeholder (#CrewLeaderTable) for the Tabulator table.

The 'click' event handler for the #btnCrewLeader button manages instantiating Tabulator as follows:

```
        $(document).on('click', '#btnCrewLeader', function () {
            //Remove the button.....
            $("div").remove(".btnCrewLeader");
            //Instantiate the Tabulator editable table
            $("#CrewLeaderTable").tabulator({
                height: "100%",
                layout: "fitColumns",
                //responsiveLayout: "hide",
                data: tabledata,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Phase", field: "phase", hozAlign: "center", editor: "select" },
                    { title: "Start Time", field: "start", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor },
                    { title: "Finish Time", field: "finish", hozAlign: "center", sorter: "time", editor: timeEditor }
                ]
            });
```

I have a couple of lines of data stored in the "datatable" array for testing purposes.

Clicking on the button fires the event handler but the Tabulator instance is not created.

As noted, I'm able to create Tabulator tables on static  elements but I really need to be able to bind to dynamically-created  elements as well.  I have browsed the Tabulator documentation but find no reference to this issue.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn’t really any difference between creating a tabulator instance on static elements or dynamically added elements. You should check and make sure that your element you are trying to bind to actually exists at the time. (I have no experience with the jQuery wrapper for Tabulator, so I assume what you’re doing to create it is valid.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where I create a new div and attach it to the body of the document.  Then I create a Tabulator with it.
https://jsfiddle.net/8hcjbatz/

This is the general idea, where options would be your Tabulator options.

```
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  const table = new Tabulator(div, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Using the createElement() method worked perfectly.

Comment: R Powell, if this answer helped, would you mind marking it as the correct answer to help others find it :)